# MYSQL Select Latest Record of Group Spanning Multiple Months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of about 50k rows where I've stored the last couple of years worth of stock market quarterly earnings announcement dates. The problem is a company could delay their announcement date after I've stored the record (I'm pulling new dates nightly), and my "earnings_calendar_archive" table ends up looking something like this:

```
id  symbol  date
48095   AEG 12/13/2018
48013   AEG 12/6/2018
47942   AEG 11/29/2018
47873   AEG 11/22/2018
47774   AEG 11/15/2018
47381   AEG 11/8/2018
45963   AEG 8/16/2018
45843   AEG 8/9/2018
45325   AEG 6/28/2018
45327   AEG 6/28/2018
45300   AEG 6/21/2018
45272   AEG 6/14/2018
45236   AEG 6/7/2018
45196   AEG 5/31/2018
45159   AEG 5/24/2018
45113   AEG 5/17/2018
45010   AEG 5/10/2018
43705   AEG 2/15/2018
42797   AEG 11/9/2017
41550   AEG 8/10/2017
40238   AEG 5/11/2017
38335   AEG 2/17/2017
36677   AEG 11/10/2016
33877   AEG 8/11/2016
30956   AEG 5/12/2016
```

The delay is almost always exactly 7 days, but it could be 14, and I've also seen delays of only a few days. I have this reasonably solved moving forward by simply checking to see if a date exists for a certain symbol within the last few weeks and deleting it before inserting the new record, but I need to fix my historical data. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT max(id) as id, symbol, max(`earnings_calendar_archive`.`date`) as date
FROM earnings_calendar_archive 
GROUP BY symbol, year(`earnings_calendar_archive`.`date`),month(`earnings_calendar_archive`.`date`) 
ORDER BY symbol ASC, date DESC
```

This works pretty well, but in the event of a delay spanning two months, it keeps both records:

```
id  symbol  date
48095   AEG 12/13/2018
47942   AEG 11/29/2018
45963   AEG 8/16/2018
45327   AEG 6/28/2018
45196   AEG 5/31/2018
43705   AEG 2/15/2018
42797   AEG 11/9/2017
41550   AEG 8/10/2017
40238   AEG 5/11/2017
38335   AEG 2/17/2017
36677   AEG 11/10/2016
33877   AEG 8/11/2016
30956   AEG 5/12/2016
```

As you can see in the result, there are two sets of rows that provide an incorrect announcement date. The first is 12/13 and 11/29 when I want it to favor 12/13, and again when they continuously delayed the announcement from 5/10 all the way to 6/28 where I would want the query to favor 6/28. If I wanted to track analytics such as stock performance following an earnings announcement, I would get bad data as there are two dates in this example where the earnings announcement did not occur. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  What duplicates?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: How are we supposed to assert that 13th dec and 29th nov are related? Are you saying you want the MAX(date) GROUP BY quarter (i.e. 3 months). If so, divide your `(MONTH(date)-1) / 3` (might also need to floor it) to convert months `1,2,3 -> 0`, `4,5,6->1` etc

Comment: @CaiusJard "How are we supposed to assert that 13th dec and 29th nov are related?" - That is exactly my challenge. I will experiment with your suggestion, thank you for contributing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated my question to provide clarity around what I am trying to achieve. Thank you for contributing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something clicked for me when @CaiusJard said: "Are you saying you want the MAX(date) GROUP BY quarter". This seems obvious in hindsight but I never thought of it. If anyone happens to run into a similar problem, this is how I solved it.

```
SELECT symbol, max(`earnings_calendar_archive`.`date`) as date
FROM earnings_calendar_archive 
GROUP BY symbol, 
year(`earnings_calendar_archive`.`date`),
quarter(`earnings_calendar_archive`.`date`)
```

Comment: And I never realised that MySQL has a Quarter() function- my learning day. Keeping track of all these different databases' functions is quite a challenge

Answer (score 0):

The best that I can figure out is that you want records where there is no following record for, say, 2 months or so.

If so, then something like this:

```
select eac.*
from earnings_calendar_archive eac
where not exists (select 1
                  from earnings_calendar_archive eac2
                  where eac2.symbol = eac.symbol and
                        eac2.date > eac.date and
                        eac2.date < eac.date + interval 60 day
                 );
```